# magento - Custom Query

Tags: magento

When I used below code for a custom query in Magento, then it works fine.

```
 $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = 'SELECT * FROM sales_order_custom';
    $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

But when I change,

```
$sql        = 'SELECT * FROM sales_order_custom WHERE key = "catalog_code"';
```

it give empty result.

Comment: Both are different queries.one is simple select and other is conditional query . what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  $sql = SELECT * FROM sales_order_custom WHERE `key`= "catalog_code"'

Answer (score 0):

A similar query to yours works like a charm...

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_page WHERE title='About  Us'";
$rows = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
var_dump($rows);
die();
```

anyways it would be better to use something like, but thats another story:

```
$connection->select()->from(.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to get customer full record in magento..
name, address, pincode, email, contact number

```
 SELECT concat((SELECT `value` FROM `customer_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=5 AND `entity_id`= '$pup_owner'),' ', (SELECT `value` FROM `customer_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=7 AND `entity_id`= '$pup_owner')) as `owner_name`,

 concat((SELECT `value` FROM `customer_address_entity_text` WHERE `entity_id`= (select `value` FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `entity_id`='$pup_owner' AND `attribute_id`=14)), ',',(SELECT `value` FROM `customer_address_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=26 AND `entity_id`= (select `value` FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `entity_id`='$pup_owner' AND `attribute_id`=14)),',' ,(SELECT `value` FROM `customer_address_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=28 AND `entity_id`= (select `value` FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `entity_id`='$pup_owner' AND `attribute_id`=14))) as `owner_address`,

 concat((SELECT `value` FROM `customer_address_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=30 AND `entity_id`= (select `value` FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `entity_id`='$pup_owner' AND `attribute_id`=14)),'') as `owner_pincode` ,

 concat((SELECT `email` FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `entity_id`= '$pup_owner'),'') as `owner_email` ,

 concat((SELECT `value` FROM `customer_address_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=31 AND `entity_id`= (select `value` FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `entity_id`='$pup_owner' AND `attribute_id`=14)),'') as `owner_contact`
```